# How to get id_token from TokenEndpoint of IdentityServer4 through authorization_code flow?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

I would like to get "access_token" and "id_token" from Token endpoint through Authorization Code flow. But, I am getting "invalid_grant" error while calling the token endpoint with following parameters on postman.

```
POST /connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2000
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a8a29659-0ea3-e7dc-3bd6-6e6630a7370d

client_id=client
&client_secret=client
&grant_type=authorization_code
&username=admin
&password=admin
&scope=openid+profile
```

Client Configuration:

```
new Client
{
   ClientId = "client",
   ClientSecrets =
   {
     new Secret("client".Sha256())
   },
   AllowedGrantTypes = new List<string> { OidcConstants.GrantTypes.AuthorizationCode },
   AllowedScopes = {
     StandardScopes.OpenId.Name,
     StandardScopes.Profile.Name,
   }
}
```

What is wrong in my client configuration section? and, How do i make a successful post request to Token Endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authorization code grant type requires a `code` parameter to be sent during the token request (see [RFC6749 section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3)).

This code is issued by the authorization server after the resource owner authorized the client (see [RFC6749 section 4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2)).